# How to show stats in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a servers management on Django.
My main model is `Server` model which has the following fields:
Domains, Databases, Emails, Memory Usage, Disk Usage and Cpu Usage.

Lets say I'm running 5-10 servers.
How can I load them and generate correctly to html so it will be shown as stats box (not table) like this image (I want to see 4-5 stats boxes):

[image]

`views.py`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super( analyze, self ).get_context_data( **kwargs )
    servers_stats=[]
    for e in Servers.objects.all():
        servers_stats.append(e.scan_name)
    context['servers'] = servers_stats
    return context
```

`HTML`:

```
<span>Databases</span><span class="pull-right">(/10)</span>
<div class="progress progress-xs">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-lilac" role="progressbar" aria-    valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 70%"></div>
</div><!-- /.progress -->
{%  for db in scans %}
<span>{{ db }}</span><span class="pull-right">({{ id }})</span>                                                      
<div class="progress progress-xs">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="78" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 78%">
</div></div><!-- /.progress -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Loop over `servers` in your template.